# Prevent image overflow TTScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, three20

How do you prevent TTScrollView's images from overflowing to the adjacent screens?

Have tried setting the frame to limit the image in a few locations and logging offsets, haven't found that works.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with the TTScrollView myself, but perhaps you could  setting the `clipsToBounds` property to `YES` might help if its a standard scrollView extension.

Comment: Tried.. doesn't fix it. I guess I'm wondering how to deal with variable page widths in a scroll view.